# Recover a Maven encrypted password?

Tags: maven, password-encryption, password-recovery

I have Maven set up for password encryption with a master password, and some time ago I encrypted a password with that and stored it in my `settings.xml`. The password is successfully in use by Maven plugins.

Now I want to recover that password for use outside Maven (performing an operation manually using a web browser). Is there a command to simply print the decrypted version of a server password?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314379/maven-password-encryption-for-other-properties is a hint.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [maven-settings-decoder](https://github.com/jelmerk/maven-settings-decoder) tool.